# How to stop '01' from importing as 1?

Tags: excel

I have a query that imports a sheet from another workbook, and one of the fields it imports is the "Rev" which is stored as 01, 02, 03, etc. as Text. However, the query always pulls these in as 1, 2, 3, etc.

How can I force it to be '0n'?
Do I have to reformat the value every time its referenced?

Comment: During the import step from another workbook you are able to use "Transform data". This tool makes it possible to assign data types for a specific column. I guess that you then use "Update" to refresh the contents. If you import data by using other methods you may need other solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT()` with just one parameter to do this.  For example `=CONCAT(Sheet2!A1)`

Answer (score 0):

From here we get it into Power Query

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Loading from Power Query back to Excel

[image]